# Фреймворк 960gs: именование классов

Tags: html, css

Вопросы по фреймворку 960gs; я понимаю его принцип работы, с этим проблем нет, но напрашивается вопрос: как именно, с чего начать его разработку? Я пока вижу 2 варианта:

1. верстать теми классами, которые есть и потом начинать их переименовывать в человекопонятные названия.
2. сразу называть классы нужными названими и сразу переименовывать в CSS.

Раскажите о вашем процессе разработки на этом фреймворке?

Comment: может это просто подложка, что бы перед версткой поверх нее верстать ? типа как в фотошопе, рисуют поверх сетки.

Comment: погуглил, нашел видео, оказалось к классам дописывают атрибуты и по ним уже происходит то что нужно, даже не знаю насколько это правильно.

Comment: Не нужно ничего менять, их классы это просто сетка к которым вы добавите свои стили, что вам мешает добавлять 2-3 класса на объект?